# How to pass array of datetime64[ns] to pybind11 without copying

Tags: numpy, pybind11

I am trying to pass an array of `datetime64[ns]` into C++ using pybind11. For arrays of integers or floating point values, one can simply use the wrapper `py::array_t<int64_t or double>`.

Is there a dedicated type in pybind11 for `datetime64[ns]` in C++ side so that I can capture as `py::array_t<DateTime>`?

As a sub-optimal solution, it would be already a great improvement if I can instead pass the underlying storage of a `datetime64[ns]` array which is expected to be stored as an array of int64. Is there any light way (i.e., no copy) to pass this as an array of int64?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the most ergonomic, but you could probably use `py::array_t<int64_t>` as the pybind11 interface's type, and convert the array (without copy) like this:

```py
In [1]: a = np.array([np.datetime64(x, 'ns') for x in range(10)])

In [2]: v = a.view(dtype=np.int64)

In [3]: v
Out[3]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int64)

In [4]: some_pybind_method(v)
```

[There's a way](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/custom.html) to write a custom type conversion that does this transparently, but I'm not familiar with the required Python C-API needed for this.